# IIS Application Initialization in Azure shows 500's periodically after an Upgrade Deployment

Tags: iis, azure, iis-8

Recently, I implemented Application Initialization in one of our Azure projects in order to minimise the time it takes for each of the sites to warm up.

I essentially have implemented *near exactly* the steps outlined in [This blog post](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/).

On a fresh deployment, it works for all 10 of my sites in IIS. The problem is though, when I then try and Upgrade that deployment I get 500 errors for the first 25 requests or so **for each site**.

Now, this isn't ideal, as instead of hitting each site once to warmup after a deployment, I now have to load each site around 25 times before I get past the 500s. They don't stop there though, they seem to sporadically happen.

If I re-image the machines post-deployment, that fixes the issue. At the cost of downtime though, which isn't an option.

Any ideas?

I have the following:

Startup task in ServiceDefinition.csdef to turn on the Application Initialization Module:

```
<Task commandLine="enableApplicationInitializationIIS.cmd" executionContext="elevated"></Task>
```

Then inside that task I have:

```
PKGMGR.EXE /iu:IIS-ApplicationInit
```

In the ServiceConfiguration.csfg I have set up the latest `osFamily`:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Foo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
```

Then in the Web Role, I have the following to turn on all the Application Initialization required settings:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
            {
                foreach (var application in site.Applications)
                {
                    application["preloadEnabled"] = true;
                }

                site.ServerAutoStart = true;
            }

            serverManager.ApplicationPoolDefaults.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
            serverManager.ApplicationPoolDefaults.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
            serverManager.ApplicationPoolDefaults["startMode"] = "AlwaysRunning";

            foreach (var appPool in serverManager.ApplicationPools)
            {
                appPool["startMode"] = "AlwaysRunning";
            }

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally, each of my sites have the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization skipManagedModules="true">
        <add initializationPage="/" />
    </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Not sure what `skipManagedModules` is though?

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia As it's your blog post, I was wondering if you could provide any insights? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the only thing I have to say is that in-place upgrades are just a bad idea. What if the upgrade fails in the middle? You should create a staging deployment, then swap it.

Comment: @sharptooth We do have 2 deployments, staging and production. I'm testing this thoroughly on staging before it goes to production. Then we'll deploy production to staging, then do the swap.

Comment: You shouldn't need in-place upgrades then.

Comment: @sharptooth We do because we Upgrade Staging, then do the switch to production. Which would yield the 500s

Comment: This is Very Bad Idea, because if if slightly trash your staging that damage will persist forever and it will not be reproducible. The right way is that you create a new staging, check it, swap, then delete the previous production (which is now staging).

Comment: @sharptooth Fair point, but that's not really an option in our scenario as we'd have to update all of the DNS entries for each deployment.

Comment: Why? Just have a CNAME mapping to yourservice.cloudapp.net and then your URL will always be mapped to production deployment.

Comment: @sharptooth The Staging instance doesn't have CNAME mapping, they're only for Production. Staging gets a random string of characters for it's CNAME.

Comment: Do you have the event logs on the machine to see what the cause of the 500 errors are ? Have you RDP in to have a look? Do you connect to for example a database some cache that might be having problems in the upgrade situation ? For example Cache / Database might be running out of connections?

Comment: You are getting 500s because you have clients hitting the server before it is fully deployed.  We constantly update a production site with 10,000 users per day.  We follow the standard Azure procedures - deploy new code to staging and test @ <guid>.cloudapp.net, then when ready, swap the VIP.  The Azure load balancer gracefully handles moving clients from old instances to new instances.

Answer (score 2):

I experience a similar issue and found your post. In my case this issue was already there with an initial deployment and as well with an upgrade deployment.

In my error logs I found a "Value cannot be null" exception. It seems that the ServerManager was not able to initialize - the code inside the using statement was not executed. It turned out I tried to deploy the assembly Microsoft.Web.Administration (from Windows 7) to a Windows Server 2012 machine.

After applying the correct version, the 500 errors disappeared.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager' threw an exception. 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager..ctor(ServerManager owner, String applicationHostConfigurationPath)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager..ctor(String applicationHostConfigurationPath)
```

**EDIT:**

I continued to experience 500 Errors at initialization and it seems that these happen because of 2 tags:

```
<applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="app_starting.htm" skipManagedModules="true" >
    <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

Removing the remapManagedRequestsTo and skipManagedModules attributes seems to remove the 500 errors see [IIS 7.5 Application Initialization for ASP.NET web service (warmup) without remapping requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348621/iis-7-5-application-initialization-for-asp-net-web-service-warmup-without-rema/15367638#15367638).