# A simple application warmup method for Azure Web Sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to use the IIS application warmup or initialization feature of IIS that makes a site load faster instead of having long wait times the first time or anything that fulfills a similar purpose. I found this article:
[Configuring an Azure Website with application warmup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154402/configuring-an-azure-website-with-application-warmup)

Frankly, I don't know what a web role is or what it does. I have a azure web site and I'm fairly new to development all around. Is there a reasonably simple way I can keep my application warmed up to avoid all those long load times? I've read a variety of articles and they either don't apply to azure or seem to require a VM/Web Role which I'm completely unfamiliar with.

There's a similar question here: [ASP.NET warmup/initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854243/asp-net-warmup-initialize)

This one didn't get an answer either. Frankly, I'm just looking for anything that will make the site not feel so sluggish so often.

Comment: To help you understand web roles better: they're stateless Windows Server VMs with nearly full control of the VM via startup tasks/scripts, and no need for you to ever worry about the OS. I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role/10941526#10941526) to highlight some core differences between the two.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty helpful, unfortunately I don't feel knowledgeable enough to move up to a web role just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep you app warm by using end point monitoring on the management portal (check out the DASHBOARD tab). You will need to have your site in Standard mode though (in the SCALE tab).